# CKEditor not capturing data from ASP.NET textbox after postback

Tags: asp.net, textbox, ckeditor, postback

My CKEditor control is displayed nicely. However, when I click save and the page posts back, I cannot get the new text from the control.
See below where I've tried to retrieve the value. No matter what I do, I'm getting the old value.

Note: I don't want to use the CKEditor ASP.NET control as it uses an old version of CKEditor that has some very annoying bugs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.ckeditor').ckeditor(function () { }, { toolbar: 'Editprofile' });
    });
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="tbDescription_en" CssClass="ckeditor" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'tbDescription_en.Text is equal to old value here
    Else
        'tbDescription_en.Text is equal to old value here
    End If
End Sub

 Protected Sub lbSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbSave.Click
   'tbDescription_en.Text is equal to old value here
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem lies in the fact that I'm using a linkbutton. I replaced it with a regular button and it now all works.
Reason is that a linkbutton does not do a direct postback.